# How to add "Edit Shortcuts" icon to Wordpress customizer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.7

How to add "Edit Shortcuts" icon new feature in WordPress 4.7 to the customizer. I want to add this icon anywhere in my theme customizer

[image: Wordpress Edit Shortcut icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called 'Visible Edit Shortcuts' in Customizer Preview. You should read more about it here:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/10/visible-edit-shortcuts-in-the-customizer-preview/

It's an extension of the selective refresh:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport        = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport = 'postMessage';

$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.site-title a',
    'render_callback' => 'twentyfifteen_customize_partial_blogname',
) );
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogdescription', array(
    'selector' => '.site-description',
    'render_callback' => 'twentyfifteen_customize_partial_blogdescription',
) );
```

Where the render callbacks call `bloginfo( 'name' );` and `bloginfo( 'description' );`

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

Also check out the official [Customizer documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#selective-refresh-fast-accurate-updates)

So basically if you had the selective refresh in your customizer, these will appear by default ;)

Comment: I have a normal text control and I want to change it without refresh customizer live preview.  ' $wp_customize->add_setting( 'copyright_text', array(
   'default'           => 'copyright',
   'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
  )
 );
 $wp_customize->add_control( 'copyright_text', array(
   'label'   => __( 'Footer copyright text' ),
   'section' => 'footer_section',
  )
 );'

Comment: What if I use direct javascript api instead of ajax refresh? How do I then create this edit shortcut?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd move away from customizer, as the plan is to replace it with full site editing and Gutenberg. So my advice is: focus on gutenberg, blocks and full site editing instead of wasting your time on things that will be removed from the WP core soon